# cannot visulize /scan in rviz after conversion of depth image to laserscan

Tags: ros-noetic, depthimage-to-laserscan

i'm using intelrealsense 435d,ros-noetic.
recently i used depthimage_to_laserscan package for my conversion as a result a topic /scan is being published ,but when i echo or visualize the /scan topic in terminal and rviz respectively i couldn't see any laserscan data.

thanks in advance .
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add more information, is the depthimage_to_laserscan image subscriber really connected to camera depth_image topic, what do you see in the node graph with rqt?

Comment: yes the depthimage_to_laserscan image subscribes  to camera depth_image

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible that it is because you are not able to subscribe to `/camera_info`. You could try remapping the `/t_camera_info` topic so that the `depthimage_to_laserscan` node can subscribe to it as `/camera_info`.